# Issues with date filtering in a macro

Tags: vba, excel, date, filtering

I need to be able to run a macro to filter a column to display all dates before today's date.

Here is what I have so far, however for some reason when I run the macro it returns nothing:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$K$2815").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=CStr("<" & CDate(Format(Now(), "DD/MM/YY"))), Operator:=xlAnd End Sub
```

Anyone know why this isn't working and how to fix it?

Comment: Testing this code, I'm getting no errors, it is behaving as I would expect.  Are you seeing the filter drop boxes at the top (header) row?

Comment: The filter headers are visible, but the data isnt.

Comment: Why are you using CDate?  You're already converting Now to a date by using Format.

Comment: Could that be causing the problem? I read that using dateserial might help with this..